# Facebook application access for the public

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Ive created my first facebook app. Basically the canvas/iframe version.
It all seems ok ..except:

1. I can only access the apps page:   (http://apps.facebook.com/hoo_promo/) when im logged in as the administrator user of the app. It should be viewable by everone. Ive submiited it to the appstore...does this matter?  is this the issue?
2. My like-gate doesnt seem to work, even though ive followed several examples. My admin user, who im logged in with, has the page liked, but the code

   **$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
   $like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];**

   for page-like is never set in the signed_request obj.

Any help much appreciated....ive added my current code...maybe this can also help others...

```
$app_id = "secretblahblahhiddenthis";
$secret = 'secretblahblahhiddenthis';
$canvas_page = "http://www.houseofoak.co.uk/facebook_app/";
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $secret,
'cookie' => true,
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$user = $facebook->getUser();

$page = 'unliked';
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_likes'));
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

if (($user) && ($like_status)){
    $page = 'liked'; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For your problems:

1. Check to make sure you aren't in sandbox mode. Visit https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/advanced to check.
2. What you're trying to do is no longer allowed. Facebook has deprecated most of the methods that make a like gate possible. See [Facebook Platform Policies Section IV. Point 1](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration) says "You must not ... gate content behind ... Facebook social channels...."

Comment: Late night last night....i did sandbox it!
And regarding the like gate....just to confirm...there is NO WAY i can see if a user has liked a certain page?

Does anyone know if you can check a users pagelist for a specific liked page...??

Comment: And why does this page do what i want???

https://www.facebook.com/illamasqua/app_4949752878

confused.

Comment: If you've got a user's id, yes you can query the [page_fan](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/) table and know if a particular user has liked a specific page. Your referenced example is an FBML app. You haven't been able to create a new one for at least a year. That app currently grandfathered in, but will cease working on July 5. See the [developer roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) for details.